# char vs varchar for performance in stock database

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, varchar

I'm using mySQL to set up a database of stock options. There are about 330,000 rows (each row is 1 option). I'm new to SQL so I'm trying to decide on the field types for things like option symbol (varies from 4 to 5 characters), stock symbol (varies from 1 to 5 characters), company name (varies from 5 to 60 characters).

I want to optimize for speed. Both creating the database (which happens every 5 minutes as new price data comes out -- i don't have a real-time data feed, but it's near real-time in that i get a new text file with 330,000 rows delivered to me every 5 minutes; this new data completely replaces the prior data), and also for lookup speed (there will be a web-based front end where many users can run ad hoc queries).

If I'm not concerned about space (since the db lifetime is 5 minutes, and each row contains maybe 300 bytes, so maybe 100MBs for the whole thing) then what is the fastest way to structure the fields?

Same question for numeric fields, actually: Is there a performance difference between int(11) and int(7)? Does one length work better than another for queries and sorting?

Thanks!

Comment: The major bottleneck in your application is due to dropping and recreating your database every five minutes. You're not going to get much performance benefit out of microenhancements like choosing char over varchar. I believe you have some more serious architectural problems to address instead.

Comment: Actually, you will get performance benefits out of choosing char over varchar. It's not a micro enhancement by any means.

Answer (score 34):

In MyISAM, there is some benefit to making fixed-width records.  VARCHAR is variable width.  CHAR is fixed-width.  If your rows have only fixed-width data types, then the whole row is fixed-width, and MySQL gains some advantage calculating the space requirements and offset of rows in that table.  That said, the advantage may be small and it's hardly worth a possible tiny gain that is outweighed by other costs (such as cache efficiency) from having fixed-width, padded CHAR columns where VARCHAR would store more compactly.

The breakpoint where it becomes more efficient depends on your application, and this is not something that can be answered except by you testing both solutions and using the one that works best for your data under your application's usage.

Regarding INT(7) versus INT(11), this is irrelevant to storage or performance.  It is a common misunderstanding that MySQL's argument to the INT type has anything to do with size of the data -- it doesn't.  MySQL's INT data type is always 32 bits.  The argument in parentheses refers to how many digits to pad if you display the value with ZEROFILL.  E.g. INT(7) will display 0001234 where INT(11) will display 00000001234.  But this padding only happens as the value is displayed, not during storage or math calculation.

Answer (score 6):

If the actual data in a field can vary a lot in size, varchar is better because it leads to smaller records, and smaller records mean a faster DB (more records can fit into cache, smaller indexes, etc.). For the same reason, using smaller ints is better if you need maximum speed.

OTOH, if the variance is small, e.g. a field has a maximum of 20 chars, and most records actually are nearly 20 chars long, then char is better because it allows some additional optimizations by the DB. However, this really only matters if it's true  for ALL the fields in a table, because then you have fixed-size records. If speed is your main concern, it might even be worth it to move any non-fixed-size fields into a separate table, if you have queries that use only the fixed-size fields (or if you only have shotgun queries).

In the end, it's hard to generalize because a lot depends on the access patterns of your actual app.

Answer (score 4):

Given your system constraints I would suggest a varchar since anything you do with the data will have to accommodate whatever padding you put in place to make use of a fixed-width char. This means more code somewhere which is more to debug, and more potential for errors. That being said:

> The major bottleneck in your application is due to dropping and recreating your database every five minutes. You're not going to get much performance benefit out of microenhancements like choosing char over varchar. I believe you have some more serious architectural problems to address instead. – Princess

I agree with the above comment. You have bigger fish to fry in your architecture before you can afford to worry about the difference between a char and varchar. For one, if you have a web user attempting to run an ad hoc query and the database is in the process of being recreated, you are going to get errors (i.e. "database doesn't exist" or simply "timed out" type issues).

I would suggest that instead you build (at the least) a quote table for the most recent quote data (with a time stamp), a ticker symbol table and a history table. Your web users would query against the ticker table to get the most recent data. If a symbol comes over in your 5-minute file that doesn't exist, it's simple enough to have the import script create it before posting the new info to the quote table. All others get updated and queries default to the current day's data.

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely not recreate the database each time.  Instead I would do the following:

- read in the update/snapshot file and create some object based on each row.
- for each row get the symbol/option name (unique) and set that in the database

If it were me I would also have an in memory cache of all the symbols and the current price data.

Price data is never an int - you can use characters.

The company name is probably not unique as there are many options for a particular company.  That should be an index and you can save space just using the id of a company.

As someone else also pointed out - your web clients do not need to have to hit the actual database and do a query - you can probably just hit your cache.  (though that really depends on what tables and data you expose to your clients and what data they want)

Having query access for other users is also a reason NOT to keep removing and creating a database.

Answer (score 1):

Also remember that creating databases is subject to whatever actual database implementation you use. If you ever port from MySQL to, say, Postgresql, you will discover a very unpleasant fact that creating databases in postgresql is a comparatively very slow operation. It is orders of magnitude slower than reading and writing table rows, for instance.

It looks like there is an application design problem to address first, before you optimize for performance choosing proper data types.